# javascript array or matrix solution needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, matrix

Im trying to code an online scorecard for our mini golf but I cant seem to figure out how to make this work without copying the same function twice. I would like to be able to make it work for 2-4 players. Here is my code:

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Trou</th>
            <th>Par</th>
            <th><input type="text" value="#1"></th> 
        <th><input type="text" value="#2"></th> 
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<?  for($i=1;$i<19;$i++){   ?>    
        <tr >
          <td><? echo $i; ?></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="number" name="qty" id="qty"/></td>  
      <td><input onblur="findTotal2()" type="number" name="qty2" id="qty2"/></td>             
        </tr>
<?  }  ?>
      <tr >
          <td>Total</td>
          <td>52</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total"/></td>       
      <td><input type="text" name="total2" id="total2"/></td>     
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

```
    function findTotal(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
    }
 
    function findTotal2(){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty2');
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById('total2').value = tot;
    }
```

I am trying to make this function work for 1-4 players without copying the same function more than once

Answer (score 0):

You could add arguments to the function like so:

```js
    function findTotal(qty_element_name, total_element_name){
        var arr = document.getElementsByName(qty_element_name);
        var tot=0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
        }
        document.getElementById(total_element_name).value = tot;
    }
```

then call it with those arguments where necessary

```
<td><input onblur="findTotal('qty', 'total')" type="number" name="qty" id="qty"/></td>  
<td><input onblur="findTotal('qty2', 'total2')" type="number" name="qty2" id="qty2"/></td>
```